# ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a Cloud Function and it is returning me all the time the following error after importing bigquery from google.cloud

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

I've tried to install all the newest versions and remove and reinstall and persists

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding something like `google-cloud-bigquery==2.3.1` into `requirements.txt`
of your Google Cloud Function
[image]

Comment: why a specific version ?

Comment: To guarantee known and predictable behavior, that you have explicitly tested against.