# ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location) persists

Tags: google-bigquery

Yes. There is an exact same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65231632/importerror-cannot-import-name-bigquery-from-google-cloud-unknown-location). But it does not work for me.
Here's my code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client();
dataset_ref = client.dataset('hacker_news', project = "bigquery-public-data")
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref);
```

My requirements.txt:

```
google-cloud-bigquery==2.34.3
```

I'm using Python 3.9.12 ('base': conda) on VS.
Still, the same error. Hoping you could help me out, thanks.

Comment: Are you following any documentation? If yes, can you provide it? Also, may I know if you are running it locally or via Cloud Function?